# Hide rows based on cell value X AND then all following rows until value Z

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a huge Excel Spreadsheet and have certain rows marked with an "X" in Row B. Those are not important to me and I´d like to hide them.

However, I would also like to hide the rows following "X", until another value comes.

See screenshot: Basically its an export of the windows file structure and I would like to hide Rows 576 - 589.

Can I use the "structure" |   |   +--- in Row A as stop condition?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the data you want to show consistently starts with |   |   +, then you could use a combination of the IF and LEFT formulas and auto filter.

=LEFT(A2,"and the number of characters your start has) to pull allow IF to find |   |   + putting a X in column B allowing you to do use an auto filter on that column.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully, that gives you some ideas.